# Basic loops in C - How to find the sum of factors

Tags: c, while-loop, sum, logic

I'm about 4 weeks into my C course, and working on a program that would essentially output the following -

```
 ./perfect
Enter number: 6
The factors of 6 are:
1
2
3
6
Sum of factors = 12
6 is a perfect number

./perfect
Enter number: 1001
The factors of 1001 are:
1
7
11
13
77
91
143
1001
Sum of factors = 1344
1001 is not a perfect number
```

My work so far -

```
// Testing if a number is perfect

#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

//Define Variables
    int input, sum;
    int n;

//Obtain input
    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d", &input);

//Print factors
    printf("The factors of %d are:\n", input);

    n = 1;
    while (n <= input) {
        if (input % n == 0) {
            printf("%d\n", n);

        }

        n = n + 1;

    }
    //Sum of factors
    //printf("Sum of factors = %d", sum);

    //Is it a perfect number?
    if (sum - input == input) {
        printf("%d is a perfect number", input);
    } else if (sum - input == !input) {
        printf("%d is not a perfect number", input);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

So I have the first and last part done (I think). It's just summing the factors inbetween that I'm struggling with.

How do I add all the factors together? Should it be part of the first while loop, or put separately?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean `if (sum - input == input) {` to be `if ((sum - input) == input) {`?

Comment: `if (sum - input == input) {`  should be `if (sum == input) {` and the `else` clause doesn't need any `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

//Define Variables
int input, sum;
int n;

//Obtain input
printf("Enter number: ");
scanf("%d", &input);

//Print factors
printf("The factors of %d are:\n", input);

for (n=1, sum=0; n <= input; n++) {
    if (input % n == 0) {
        printf("%d\n", n);
        sum += n;
    }
}
//Sum of factors
//printf("Sum of factors = %d", sum);

//Is it a perfect number?
if ((sum - input) == input) {
    printf("%d is a perfect number", input);
} else {
    printf("%d is not a perfect number", input);
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  I would initialize sum=0 at the top and add sum += n; to the first while loop.  That should do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in the first loop. For instance,

```
    factorsSum = 0;
    while (n <= input) {
    if (input % n == 0) {
        printf("%d\n", n);
        factorsSum += n;
    }
```

Hope this helps  =)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've added that and am getting a strange output... so I've updated the first while loop to

`    n = 1;
    sum = 0;
    while (n <= input) {
        if (input % n == 0) {
            printf("%d\n", n);
            sum += n;
            printf("Sum of factors = %d", sum);

        }

        n = n + 1; `

and now get the following output<br>

Enter number: 6
The factors of 6 are:
1
Sum of factors = 12
Sum of factors = 33
Sum of factors = 66
Sum of factors = 126 is a perfect number

Not sure what happened here...

Comment: It looks like your 
     printf("Sum of factors = %d", sum);
is actually inside a loop, have you checked on that?

Comment: Thank you @Luanf, that helped me get past the roadblock I was having.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sum =0;

    for (var i=1, sum=0; i <= input/2; i++) {
           if (input % i == 0) {
               printf("%d\n", n);
               sum += i;
           }    
}    
//Sum of factors    
//printf("Sum of factors = %d", sum);
```

this code will work perfect for you.
with fewer number of loop counts
for more information [see here](http://ccodinggeek.blogspot.in/)

Comment: If you want to reduce loop count, looping to sqrt(input) is sufficient.